# how to subract in ascending order based on listbox

Tags: mysql, vb.net, listbox

i have a listbox and these items are loaded on listbox 1

```
PRODUCTS     METERS
productA     100
productB      70
productC      20
productD       5
```

what i want to do is when a user presses a 'ENTER' the program should subtract in ascending order based on the meters.

```
  Dim x As Integer
    Dim ans As Decimal
    x = ListBox1.Items.Count


    Dim da As New SqlDataAdapter
    Dim strcnn As New SqlConnection
    Dim cmd As New SqlCommand
    Try
        strcnn.ConnectionString = ClsFuncs.connstring("connectionstring1")
        strcnn.Open()
        cmd.Connection = strcnn
        ans = TextBox10.Text / x
        cmd.Connection = strcnn
        cmd.CommandText = "update " & tbl & " set quantity =quantity-" & ans & " where flg2=5    and quantity >0"
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
        MsgBox("Subtracted mass on each products", MsgBoxStyle.Information)

    Catch ex As Exception

        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, "ERROR", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error)
    Finally
        strcnn.Close()
    End Try
```

so far i have managed to use listbox.items.count as shown above but the problem is this code divides
the meters equally for example user input on textbox is 175m the code divides 175 by 4 = 43.75m
and the answer is subtracted on each product. to get to my point product C and product D ends up being negative eg product C(20m-43.75m=23.75m)

is there any code or sql query i can use to make this code subtract in ascending order?
eg user input 175m

```
productA    100-100
productB    70-70
productC    20-5
productD     5
```

such that product D will not be touched?

Comment: I don't follow what the logic is supposed to be here why does ProductA and ProductB have the current value subtracted but the others are different values? Can you should the output you are trying to get to?

Comment: the main logic is we producing a final product of 175m so when you input 175m, this 175m is produced from 3 products which are A,B,C that is 100m then 70m and finaly 5m. the others are different because the final product is already done and product A,B will have 0m while C will have 15m and D unchanged

Answer (score 0):

You have the answer right in front of you... some psudocode

- Take user input (userInput)
- If ProductA_quantity > userInput then subtract userInput from productA end
- Else if userInput > ProductA the subtract ProductA from userInput
- Continue same sequence with remaining Products until userInput = 0

Comment: thanx a lot let me work on how to interpret this in vb

Comment: Well this logic isn't quite right I don't think, you need to keep subtracting productA  until the remainder is less than productA then subtract productB in the same fashion (I think)

Comment: @Matt agree... your logic is simpler to code although I think my logic would have worked just more branches and conditions.

Comment: In fact instead of subtraction you could use Mod and get an instant quantity of the product. Then if any remainder use this value as a Mod against the next Product.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it would be better for you to do it the other way around. Instead of substracting, you do an addition.

```
select a.name, (select sum(b.meters) from products b where b.meters >= a.meters) from products a
```

With the result of the addition, you can easely find the product you need. For 175, you could get all product that returns a sum smaller than 175. (You might need to also add the next product if the sum is different than 175).